# enable_if class member function with separate definition

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if, class-members

I'm using `enable_if` class member functions to iterate over a variational template argument. Here is a minimal example (without the actual variadic)

```
#include <iostream>

template<int size> class Test {
    public:
        template<int i = 0> typename std::enable_if<i == size, void>::type test() {}

        template<int i = 0> typename std::enable_if<i < size, void>::type test() {
            std::cout << "cycle: " << i << '\n';
            test<i + 1>();
        }
};

int main(int, char**) {
    Test<10> a;
    a.test<>();
}
```

It works just fine but now I'm having problems with dependencies and decided to separate the declarations and definitions. I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int size> class Test {
    public:
        template<int i = 0> void test();
};

template<int size>
template<int i> typename std::enable_if<i == size, void>::type Test<size>::test() {}

template<int size>
template<int i> typename std::enable_if<(i < size), void>::type Test<size>::test() {
    std::cout << "cycle: " << i << '\n';
    test<i + 1>();
}

int main(int, char**) {
    Test<10> a;
    a.test<>();
}
```

but GCC says that `error: out-of-line definition of 'test' does not match any declaration in 'Test<size>'`. I managed to make it work by including definitions for both cases of `test`. My question is: why doesn't this work? Shouldn't the compiler only find one of the declarations for any `i`? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: You might be interested in [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to replace `std::enable_if`if you want to iterate over number at compile time. Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df4b15c4624e866) (can also be done in C++11)

Comment: That's great, I'll switch to that. Thanks a lot! (I had never seen that usage of ellipsis, really cool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<int i = 0> 
typename std::enable_if<i == size, void>::type test() { }

template<int i = 0> 
typename std::enable_if<i < size, void>::type test() { /* ... */ }
```

The two member functions above are completely different, they just happen to have the same name `test`. They have different signatures and must be declared separately. It's similar to writing:

```
template<int i = 0> 
int test() { }

template<int i = 0> 
float test() { /* ... */ }
```

Would you expect to be able to have a single declaration for both of those in your class definition?

Comment: Ok, then I didn't really understand what `enable_if` does. I thought that when the condition was true it simply became the type (void in this case), and when the condition failed it disappeared. So they have different return types?

Comment: @mbtg: your understanding of `enable_if` is correct, but it is nothing special - it's just a return type like any other. It disappears due to SFINAE, it's not something magical about `enable_if`. You still have **two** different function with **two** different return types - they both happen to be different instantiations of `enable_if`, but that doesn't mean that the functions are magically bundled together.

Comment: I was hoping to save some code there but I guess I can't. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the declaration inside the class with the matching signature

```
#include <iostream>

template<int size> class Test {
    public:
        template<int i = 0> typename std::enable_if<i == size, void>::type test();
    template<int i = 0> typename std::enable_if<i < size, void>::type test();
};

template<int size>
template<int i> typename std::enable_if<i == size, void>::type Test<size>::test() {}

template<int size>
template<int i> typename std::enable_if<(i < size), void>::type Test<size>::test() {
    std::cout << "cycle: " << i << '\n';
    test<i + 1>();
}

int main(int, char**) {
    Test<10> a;
    a.test<>();
}
```

Comment: You have to change `(i < size)` to `i<size` to compile